# Django - First App Part 4 - Results Page not showing up correctly

Tags: django

I'm just about finished building the Poll app and everything seems to be working except for the results page.  "Vote Again" isn't showing up, or any other data after I input a selection.  It looks like the page is just reloading.  The new votes are getting counted, and I'm not getting an error message.  I can see that I'm on the /results/ page.

Does anyone have any ideas where I should be looking for the problem?

Thanks!

Views:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

from polls.models import Choice, Poll

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_poll_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published polls."""
        return Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'polls/results.hmtl'


def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })

    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        #Always return an HttpRespsonseRedirect after successfully dealing
        #with Post data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        #user hits the Back button
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results',   args=(p.id,)))
```

URLs -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    #ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    #ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

Models

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone


class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Hoping I didn't mess up any formatting when I pasted in here.

Comment: You're going to need to upload your code here and show us what's going on. As it stands, your question is too vague.

Comment: Can I see your views.py, urls.py, models.py ?

Comment: Here they are.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is because you misspell the template page for results.

```
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'polls/results.hmtl'
```

correct the spelling for `results.html`